# Can I use the same Merchant account for two different Google Play Store developer accounts?

Tags: android, android-pay

I have a merchant account already linked to one of my developer accounts, now can I use the same Merchant account for a different Google Developer account?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, enter [Google Merchant Wallet](https://wallet.google.com/merchant) and in Configuration you can see Users or similar option, add a gmail account and set privileges.